# Docker how to map subdirectory to port

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker, and I am trying to run multiple Docker containers on the same server.

I searched and found out that I can do this [Assigning vhosts to Docker ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497564/assigning-vhosts-to-docker-ports).

Unfortunately, I cannot use wildcard DNS. Therefore, I'd like to configure using subdirectory so that (or are there any alternative solutions?):

test.com/app1 -> app1 (test.com:1234)

test.com/app2 -> app2 (test.com:0987)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use nginx like mentioned in the link you posted:

```
upstream container-1 { server 127.0.0.1:49162; }
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name container-1.yourdomain.com;
  location    /<your subdir> {
    proxy_pass  http://container-1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible directly via Docker.
You would need to use a reverse proxy like nginx or haproxy to do this.