# Simple way to run subdomains on docker container in developer environment

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have docker container build for production.

In "development mode", it uses docker-compose to fire up dependencies and link them.

The application inside container runs a site (`mycoolsite.tld`) and its subdomains (like `api.mycoolsite.tld`).

What we did is to have `mycoolsite.dev` & `api.mycoolsite.dev`, used config vars to override the app location & dnsmasq to override `*.mycoolsite.dev` to `127.0.0.1` so integration tests can download from `api.mycoolsite.dev`.

Is there a good way to utilise docker-compose to achieve that?

I don't want to run additional process in the main container. I am unsure how to link dnsmasq container and set it up to point correctly to the original one. I'd be willing to specify list of subdomains and override `/etc/hosts` via mount, but I can't do that as docker-compose overrides hosts with link. I also find out that specifying additional hostsfile is tricky. I'd like to solve that for both native linux docker as well as using docker daemon proxied through boot2docker VM.

Comment: would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497564/assigning-vhosts-to-docker-ports/23975934#23975934 work for you?

Comment: @Thomasleveil That deals with dispatching subdomains accross multiple hosts; I have dispatching done in express, I am asking about "Let say your DNS is set up so that `*.test.local` maps to the IP address of your Docker host" part of that question -- *from within the docker container*

Comment: xip.io allows you to map create any subdomain for an IP just by ending it with <the.ip>.xip.io (eg, www.192.168.0.1.xip.io resolves to 192.168.0.1) could you use `mycoolsite.127.0.0.1.xip.io` & `api.mycoolsite.127.0.0.1.xip.io` as host names? another resource that could help you : https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jwilder/nginx-proxy/

Comment: I'd love not to rely on external resources...